# Getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." in the console when fetching an API in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, api

I am trying to fetch an API in SwiftUI. However, I get this error in the console when running the code:
"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

I am not sure where the error is occurring. Could you help me find a solution?

This is code I am running:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Product: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let price: Double
    let image: String
}


struct ProductRow: View {
    var product: Product
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
          
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: product.image)) { image in
                image.resizable()
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
          
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(product.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("$\(product.price, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ProuctDetail: View {
    var product: Product
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: product.image)) { image in
                image.resizable()
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .scaledToFit()
            
            
            Text(product.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Text(product.description)
                .padding()
            Text("$\(product.price, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var products = [Product]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(products) { product in
               
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product)) {
                    ProductRow(product: product)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Products")
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            fetchProducts()
        }
    }
    

    func fetchProducts() {
      
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://dummyjson.com/products") else { return }
        

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
      
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            // Check if there is any data
            if let data = data {
                
                do {
                    let decodedProducts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.products = decodedProducts
                    }
                } catch {
               
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `print(error.localizedDescription)` `print(error)`. It will tell you that the root object is a dictionary. The array you are referring to is the value for key `products`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode the JSON as an array of `Product`. But the JSON has a top-level `Products` key:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"iPhone 9",
         "description":"An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
         "price":549,
         "discountPercentage":12.96,
         "rating":4.69,
         "stock":94,
         "brand":"Apple",
         "category":"smartphones",
         "thumbnail":"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
         "images":[
            "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg",
            "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg",
            "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/3.jpg",
            "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/4.jpg",
            "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"
         ]
      },

…
```

You can fix that by declaring a `Products` struct and then decoding using `Products.self`:

```
struct Products: Decodable {
    let products: [Product]
}
```

But then you get a different error: “ The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.”

That is because your `Product` struct is expecting a `name` and `image`, which are not in the JSON. There is a `title` and an array of `images`.

You either need to change your `Product` to match the JSON or use a custom decoder to extract the fields you need.

Comment: I have removed `images` and changed `name` to `title`. I have also now edited the code so that it works with the changes I have made, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you also add the top level `Products` struct, change your JSON decoding code to decode `Products.self` instead of `[Product].self` and then use `self.products = decodedProducts.products` to access the array?